# Laravel 4.2 Queue Push Syncing When Set To Redis

Tags: laravel, redis, queue

Using Laravel 4.2 framework. Was on 4.1.x but switching back to that version, has the queue::push still firing immediately as if the queue config was set to sync but this is set to redis.

When running the queue closure, it fires the command immediately. Testing with sample output in the actual command to confirm. I can connect to the redis db without an issue with the configuration set in the config file.

Here is the syntax of my queue closure:

```
Queue::push(function($job) use ($placeId)
{
    Artisan::call('testcommandname', [$placeId]);

    $job->delete();
});
```

Not sure if I am overlooking something or what? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

So thinking this was an error due to a framework upgrade, it ended up being that I wasn't setting the correct environment configuration for queues.